# Make bins coarser on pandas dataframe, and sum in counting columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-binding, sum

I have a dataframe with a variable (E), where the value in the dataframe is the left edge of the bin, and a set of occupancies for each bin (n) (and the uncertainty squared (v)). At the moment, these are binned from 200 to 2000 in steps of 100 (usually), then binned 2000 to +inf. However these bins are very fine for the plotting I need to perform, and I need to rebin these into 200, 300, 400, 600, 1000, +inf.

**Key Point**: Because I am reading several sets of data like this from a source, not all my dataframes have entries e.g. for bin 600-700, i.e. some rows will be missing from one dataframe, while another may have entries for them. I need to rebin and sum n and v based on the new bins, while accounting for the fact that my dataframes aren't "regular".

Here's an example dataframe:

```
        E       n       v
0       200.0   26.0    1.3 
1       300.0   56.0    2.2
2       400.0   62.0    2.5
3       500.0   55.0    2.2
4       600.0   24.0    1.7
5       800.0   12.0    1.3
6       900.0   8.0     0.9
7       1000.0  4.0     0.6
8       1100.0  1.0     0.2
```

And here is my desired output:

```
        E       n       v
0       200.0   26.0    1.3 
1       300.0   56.0    2.2
2       400.0   117.0   4.7
3       600.0   44.0    3.9
4       1000.0  5.0     0.8
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cut` with `agg`

```
s=df.groupby(pd.cut(df.E,[200,300,400,600,1000,np.inf],right=False)).agg({'E':'first','n':'sum','v':'sum'})

s.E=s.index.map(lambda x :x.left)
s.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
s
        E      n    v
0   200.0   26.0  1.3
1   300.0   56.0  2.2
2   400.0  117.0  4.7
3   600.0   44.0  3.9
4  1000.0    5.0  0.8
```

Comment: This was perfect, thanks! The only difference is I had to remove `inplace=True`, because it was returning a None type, but that might be a difference between pandas versions or just the way I'm using it in my macro. Thank you again!